# Replace part of SQL string from a substring up to the next comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a comma separated string in a table that looks like this:

```
FirstTitle:name1, SecondTitle:100000, ThirdTitle:600, FourthTitle:100000, RemoveTitle:30, SixthTitle:1234
```

The 'Title' bit refers to a description of that value, the value itself is held after the ':', in other words the string is made of Title:Value pairs.

I want to remove part of the string - specifically the value with the label 'RemoveTitle'. i.e. I want this:

```
FirstTitle:name1, SecondTitle:100000, ThirdTitle:600, FourthTitle:100000, RemoveTitle:30, SixthTitle:1234
```

to become:

```
    FirstTitle:name1, SecondTitle:100000, ThirdTitle:600, FourthTitle:100000, SixthTitle:1234
```

Importantly, I can't rely on the title:value pairs being in the same order in the string, or on the length of the 'values' being the same.

I can try to use STUFF along the lines of:

```
DECLARE @StartSubString varchar(100)
SET @StartSubString = 'RemoveTitle:'

STUFF(TableName.columnName,
      CHARINDEX(@StartSubString, TableName.columnName ,1),
      ???, 
      '')
```

But In order to work out the length of the substring to Stuff, I need to know the position of the comma following the @StartSubString, which I'm not sure how to get. It may also be the last pair in the string, in which case there won't be a comma following, but I can deal with that issue.

Any help would be very helpfully received!

Comment: Don't store such strings to begin with. Use proper tables. What would be a trivial `UPDATE` query s now a very complex, very expensive operation. You gain *nothing* by storing data this way. Certainly no flexibility. If you want to store an arbitrary number of columns you can use sparse columns.  At the very least, use JSON or XML instead of a custom format. This way you'd be able to use the built-in JSON functions to update. The query would still be very slow and unable to use any indexes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yep - I know this already and it's a silly way to store it. However, the table is years old and it would be a far more expensive / risky development to address that right now.

Comment: And yet, after all these years people can't even update a value in it, or query it. If they could, you wouldn't be asking this question. You're forced to pay for delayed business transactions (that's what the end result is) but that's better than just fixing the bug?

Comment: In any case, at the very least convert this to JSON so you can use functions like `JSON_VALUE`. All supported SQL Server versions support JSON. You can replace `:` with `":"`, `,` with `","` and surround the string with `{ }` to convert the string into JSON. After modification you can modify the data with JSON_MODIFY. After that you'll have to convert back to the custom format. For older (unsupported) versions, you can convert it to XML

Comment: I don't disagree with you - it's already due to be addressed. Changing it as JSON is a good call...

Comment: Convert to JSON. After that you can use `SET @info=JSON_MODIFY(@info,'$.FirstTitle',NULL)` to delete that attribute

Comment: Are the strings delimted by comma space or just comma? Is the datatype char or varchar? Do you have trailing spaces in strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ugly as it is, the following is one way to remove your data element using standard string functions. this assumes each element is separated by `', '`, you can adjust as necesary:

```
declare @remove varchar(50)='RemoveTitle';
with sampledata as (
    select 'FirstTitle:name1, SecondTitle:100000, ThirdTitle:600, FourthTitle:100000, RemoveTitle:30, SixthTitle:1234' v
)

select v Original, Stuff(v,s.p, IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(', ',v,s.p),0),Len(v))-s.p+2,'') Replaced, s.p, CharIndex(', ',v,s.p)
from sampledata sd
cross apply (values(PatIndex(Concat('%',@remove,'%'),v)))s(p)
```

Comment: The cross apply simply returns the start position of the string to find; using *cross apply values* makes the value available in the `select` and saves having to repeat the clause multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Even the brute force method is tricky, because you have to consider a lot of different possibilities -- the string being at the beginning, end, or not present at all.  This should work under all circumstances:

```
with tablename as (
    select 'FirstTitle:name1, SecondTitle:100000, ThirdTitle:600, FourthTitle:100000, RemoveTitle:3012345, SixthTitle:1234 ' as col union all
    select 'FirstTitle:name1, SecondTitle:100000, ThirdTitle:600, FourthTitle:100000, RemoveTitle:3012345' as col union all
    select 'RemoveTitle:3012345' as col union all
    select 'FirstTitle:name1, SecondTitle:100000, ThirdTitle:600, FourthTitle:100000' as col
)
select t.col,
       coalesce(Stuff(t.col, v.loc, charindex(', ', t.col + ', ', v.loc) - v.loc+2, ''), t.col) as new_col
from tablename t cross apply
     (values (PatIndex('%' + @StartSubString +'%', t.col))
     ) v(loc);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fba4d0b1e02d4ba942d265b47d6f3327) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

You can fix the trailing comma using `trim()`:

```
   trim(', ' from coalesce(Stuff(t.col, v.loc, charindex(', ', t.col + ', ', v.loc) - v.loc+2, ''), t.col)) as new_col
```